# Change path prefix URL for multilanguage

Tags: nodes

I''ve got my drupal 8 content in 5 languages and now I'm trying to change path prefix foreach lang (e.g: zh-hant by zh).

The problem cames when trying to edit some content type and I've got a 404 error. There's no problem for the content with the new path prefix

- old url --> www.mysite.com/zh-hant/mycontent
- new url --> www.mysite.com/zh/mycontent (works fine on front)
- new edit url --> www.mysite.com/zh/mycontent/edit (Crashes with a 404)

Answer (score 0):

your node edit link should be rather something like

www.mysite.com/zh/node/NODE_ID/edit

I guess you are using the alias of the node and you are appending "/edit", which would not work usually.